# Download pdf file through selenium webdriver and then need to send on gmail

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, automation, selenium-chromedriver

I have a test case where I need to download a user report pdf that needs to download through selenium web driver and then send it to email with attachment downloaded pdf to particular user

Is it possible through selenium webdriver? if yes, then please suggest me how can I achieve it.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: It is possible. Please show us what you you tried so far, what exactly problems are you facing with

Comment: 1. On my web page there is a button download where I can download the user report pdf. 2. By clicking the download button it's downloaded pdf in local system of windows. 3. Now I need to check the downloaded file into local system as it;s downloaded or not and then send it to a perticular user on gmail with attached report.

Comment: OK, all of this is possible to do programmatically

Comment: Could you please share with me logic

Comment: The logic is exactly what you wrote in your previous comment here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**As per the logic mention by you, let's discuss all the solutions pointwise.**

1. On my web page there is a button download where I can download the user
   report pdf.
2. By clicking the download button it's downloaded pdf in the local system of windows.

**Answer: Try to download it in a specific folder by setting your default directory path.**

```
    Map<String, Object> prefs = new HashMap<>();
    prefs.put("download.prompt_for_download", false);
    String downloadFilepath = USER_DIRECTORY+"/downloads/";
    prefs.put("download.default_directory", new File(downloadFilepath) );
    ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
    options.setExperimentalOption("prefs", prefs);
    WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver(options);
```

3. Use **JavaMail API - Sending Email With Attachment** to send your pdf.
   Ref: https://www.tutorialspoint.com/javamail_api/javamail_api_send_email_with_attachment.htm